# Remove action not working in child theme

Tags: actions, child-theme

I am trying to remove action but it is not working:

How can I remove this `add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'enqueueScriptsAsync'), PHP_INT_MAX);` specific action in child theme?

```
class TidioLiveChat
{
    const SCRIPT_URL = '//code.tidio.co/';
    const API_URL = 'https://api-v2.tidio.co';
    const CHAT_URL = 'https://www.tidio.com';
    const PUBLIC_KEY_OPTION = 'tidio-one-public-key';
    const PRIVATE_KEY_OPTION = 'tidio-one-private-key';
    const ASYNC_LOAD_OPTION = 'tidio-async-load';
    const CLEAR_ACCOUNT_DATA_ACTION = 'tidio-chat-reset';
    const TIDIO_PLUGIN_NAME = 'tidio-live-chat';
    const TOGGLE_ASYNC_ACTION = 'tidio-chat-toggle-async';
    const TIDIO_ICON_BASE64 = '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';
    const TIDIO_XHR_NONCE_NAME = 'tidio-xhr-nonce';

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!empty($_GET['tidio_chat_version'])) {
            echo TIDIOCHAT_VERSION;
            exit;
        }

        /* Before add link to menu - check is user trying to unninstal */
        if (is_admin() && current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !empty($_GET['tidio_one_clear_cache'])) {
            delete_option(TidioLiveChat::PUBLIC_KEY_OPTION);
            delete_option(TidioLiveChat::PRIVATE_KEY_OPTION);
        }

        if (get_option(TidioLiveChat::PUBLIC_KEY_OPTION)) {
            add_action('admin_footer', array($this, 'adminJS'));
        }

        if (!is_admin()) {
            if (get_option(TidioLiveChat::ASYNC_LOAD_OPTION)) {
                add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'enqueueScriptsAsync'), PHP_INT_MAX);
            } else {
                add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueueScriptsSync'), 1000);
            }
        } else if (current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
            add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'addAdminMenuLink'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueueAdminScripts'));

            add_action('wp_ajax_tidio_chat_save_keys', array($this, 'ajaxTidioChatSaveKeys'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_set_project_keys', array($this, 'ajaxSetProjectKeys'));
            add_action('wp_ajax_get_private_key', array($this, 'ajaxGetPrivateKey'));

            add_action('admin_post_' . TidioLiveChat::CLEAR_ACCOUNT_DATA_ACTION . '', array($this, 'uninstall'));
            add_action('admin_post_' . TidioLiveChat::TOGGLE_ASYNC_ACTION . '', array($this, 'toggleAsync'));

            add_filter('plugin_action_links', array($this, 'pluginActionLinks'), 10, 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass the same instance of `TidioLiveChat`. Where and how is that class instantiated? You're looking for `new TidioLiveChat` somewhere.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes there at bottom $TidioLiveChat = new TidioLiveChat();

Comment: So if `$TidioLiveChat` is a global variable then you need to use that variable in place of `$this` when removing the action.